Reduce filesize when creating new workbook
I have a report with 5 worksheets + 1 with sales data, the VBA code copy the reports from the 5 tabs into a new workbook and save it locally.
Everything works fine until the code try to save it, its takes like 8-10 minutes and the file size is huge (18 Mb as XLSX and 8 Mb as XLSB) compared to 150 kB when past values in the original report and then save it manually as XLSX (I manually delete the sales data tab in this case)
What do I have to do to get the files size down to like 150-200 kB?
VBA:
Sub Export_Report()
        
    '** Source worksheet names
    Dim sWSnames() As Variant
    sWSnames = Array("Overview", "Product", "Sales", "E-com", "Inventory")
    
    '** Source Workbook (holds the code)
    Dim sWB As Workbook: Set sWB = ThisWorkbook

    '** Copy the worksheets to a new workbook
    sWB.Worksheets(sWSnames).Copy
    
    '** Destination Workbook
    Dim dWB As Workbook: Set dWB = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    Dim dWS As Worksheet
    Dim dRNG As Range
    
    '** Convert formulas to values
    For Each dWS In dWB.Worksheets
        Set dRNG = dWS.UsedRange
        dRNG.Value = dRNG.Value
    Next dWS

    '** Save..
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String

    filePath = sWB.Path
    fileName = "Report " & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")

    '** Save to same dir as sWB
    dWB.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & "\" & fileName & ".xlsb", _
    FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

    '** Close dWB
    'dWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub


The reports contains formulas and pivotchars!

How much data is in each sheet? Have you tried clearing the (apparently) empty cells from each sheet? Have you looked in the XML structure of the file to see what causes the bloat?

Thanks for your reply, cybernetic.nomad!
The largest report spans from B2 to T141 across all five sheets, the reports include both images, formulas and pivotcharts.
Should I modify the "dWS.UsedRange" to specify a specific range instead?
Additionally, the sales data (not copied from the original workbook) covers the range from A1 to AC187780.

Add Debug.Print dRNG.Address below Set dRNG = dWS.UsedRange and see if there's anything odd in the output.  UsedRange sometimes is larger than you expect.

Also check the size of the images

UsedRange can sometimes be much larger than you expect (because it doesn't just take cell content into account)
Instead of:
For Each dWS In dWB.Worksheets
    Set dRNG = dWS.UsedRange
    dRNG.Value = dRNG.Value
Next dWS

Try something like this:
'...
'...
For Each dWS In dWB.Worksheets
    ConvertFormulasToValues dWS
Next dWS
'...
'...

Called sub:
Sub ConvertFormulasToValues(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim frng As Range, a As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no formulas found
    Set frng = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    If Not frng Is Nothing Then
        For Each a In frng.Areas 'loop all areas within `frng`
            a.Value = a.Value
        Next a
    End If
End Sub

